# Moodle - CkEditor is not coming for dynamically created courses

Tags: php, ckeditor, moodle, quickform

I am new to `Moodle`, I have been developing a learning management system from past couple of weeks, which includes direct tweaks in the core code of `moodle`.

I have set of courses which has to be created from the backend of `MySQL`. When I am trying to create a course from `MySQL` (**Not Website**), then while editing the course, `ckeditor` doesn't come. It is a plain `TextArea` with an **additional dropdown**.

I am not able to understand, why is it coming like that? I have populated all proper data in the table. Is there something else which has to be done apart from just populating `summary` field in `mdl_course` table.?

Thank you.

Comment: Check your browser console for js error, how are you initiating ckeditor from JS or by css class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ... is the "text editor" option in your profile correctly set to atto or ckeditor?

Then, I wonder which field or page on which you want to see an html text editor show up. I'm thinking you are looking at the "summary" field. If so, make sure the "summaryformat" column is set to 1. While 0 is for "Moodle format", 1 stands for "HTML format".

Hopefully, this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it caused by 'old cache', try full refresh browser, [Shift]-F5.
Or clean you browser cache.
If you use firefox (I use firefox version 33) : Menu (hamburger icon on top right) > Preferences > Advance >  Network > Clear now (Cache web content)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).